# Allow input in a UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

So I have a UITableView (its in a UIPopOverController if that matters), and I want the user to be able to edit the content of the tableView.  I added a UINaviagationController, the tableView also has a title and an edit button.  Essentially what I'm asking is, when the user taps the edit button, how can I add like UITextViews to some of the tableViews and in one of the cells, a UISegmentControl and a UITextView.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Andrew,

If you do a StackOverflow search, you'll find a half a dozen good answers w/code. You can then try the code and let us know what doesn't work. This will enhance your learning/coding skills and better help us, help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add them as subviews of the cell, set correct frame to make subviews inside the cell